# Return two different custom cells in the same View Controller and without any section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to return two different custom cells in the same `ViewController` and without any section. Problem comes with method `numberOfRowsInTableView`. How do I return the count of the items in two cells? I tried the following code in `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
var indexPath = NSIndexPath()
if indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 4 {
    return abc.count
} else {
    return xyz.count
}
```

But app crashes with the error :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.'

Comment: so `abc` and `xyz` will show different cells accordingly?

Comment: What exactly is the `indexPath` in `numberOfRowsInSection` supposed to be? You're basically initialising an empty `NSIndexPath` and then checking it's `row`? It doesn't make much sense. Please also provide your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one section then numberOfRowsInSection should return just the total number of cells you will have in your UITableView. If this is fixed, just return the number if it's dynamic (ie. depending on an array) then return the dynamic size (the size of the array).

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one section, made of two kind of cells coming from two different arrays, then the number of cells in the section is the sum of the two arrays' length. Whatever the order of the cells (be it A, B, A, B, A, B... or A A A A B B B B).

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, we cannot return two multiple custom cells count. So for this we need to count elements of both the cells, whose elements are greater, then return that count.

Try this

```
    var abc = [String]()  //You can have any datatype of array
    var xyz = [String]()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
        {
            return (abc.count > xyz.count) ? abc.count : xyz.count
        }
```

Here, to display values in both the custom cells, you need to implement like this way in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.

```
    func tableView(tableViewData: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell = tableViewData.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as! CustomCellClass
        if indexPath.row < abc
        {
            cell.label1.text = abc[indexPath.row]
        }
        else
        {
            cell.label1.text = ""
        }
        if indexPath.row < self.xyz.count
        {
            cell.label2.text = xyz[indexPath.row]
        }
        else
        {
            cell.label2.text = ""
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Hope it works for you.